# Design time Intellisense support for String property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, intellisense

I'm tring to implement a control with a property of type String where i would like to store a string representation of a Type name. My problem is that i cannot manage to add an Intellisense support for this property that allows the user to browse through all the available classes (to be more precise only through all subclasses of a predefined class) while editing the property value from aspx.
I would like something like the dropdown menu you get when you edit the TypeName property of the asp ObjectDataSource class as seen in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't type it out as a literal string at all.  Instead use `typeof` to get the `Type` object corresponding to whatever type you're interested in.  By doing this you'll be entering the type as a type itself, with full compiler/IDE support.  If you *really, really* need a string, you can get the name out of that `Type` object, but you're better off just storing it as a `Type` if that's feasible.

Comment: If I declare it as a Type 

`public Type TypeName
{get; set;}`

the intellisense only shows me the list of the properties of the Type class not the list of the available classes.

Am i missing something?

Comment: @Giskard Your question implies that you're looking for IDE support for determining what type to assign to the type field.  It's going to be impossible to have the IDE tell you what the derived types are of the value of a `Type` variable.  It's variable.  It's contents aren't known at compile time, nor are they constant, so obviously there can be no constant compile time list of types.

Comment: I do not want to assign any type to any field. I would only like to store a typename into a string, exactly as the ObjectDataSource object in the image does, so i think it's possible to have the intellisense behaviour i want.

Comment: @Giskard Then you can simply do what I suggested in my answer, because that's the exact question that I answered.  Your comment implies that you're accessing the data from that property, not setting it, contrary to your question.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work as i want. As i said in my first comment if i declare it of type Type while I try to set it from the aspx page the intellisense gives me only the list of the Type class properties as in this screenshot [link](http://s3.postimg.org/c1gtxa4pf/Type_Name.jpg)

Comment: @Giskard Set it from the code behind, not the markup.